# SQL Server Data Masking Minimum permissions needed to mask

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, permissions, data-masking

I am in the process of masking some data in a SQL Server 2017 database. I have masked a column with this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE lEmployee
    ALTER COLUMN FirstName nvarchar(160) 
          MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(2,"xxx",2)')
```

And I can see in `sys.columns` that this is now masked.

Now in the application, the data is not showing as masked (neither is it in the db when logged in as that user). I have also run the below to ensure the user does not have this permission.

```
REVOKE UNMASK TO testuser
```

Can anyone advise what the minimum permissions are needed so that the data masking works as expected.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not able to `DENY UNMASK` on `sysadmin` and `db_owner`. This is build-in limitation.

Also, as noted in the documentation, this is not a [security](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47144167/1080354) feature if the user can query the table.

As it in the example of the documentation shows, you do not need to grant `REVOKE UNMASK` as it is set by default:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  [dbo].[StackOverflow];

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StackOverflow]  
  (MemberID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,  
   FirstName varchar(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'partial(1,"XXXXXXX",0)') NULL,  
   LastName varchar(100) NOT NULL,  
   Phone# varchar(12) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'default()') NULL,  
   Email varchar(100) MASKED WITH (FUNCTION = 'email()') NULL);  

INSERT [dbo].[StackOverflow] (FirstName, LastName, Phone#, Email) VALUES   
('Roberto', 'Tamburello', '555.123.4567', 'RTamburello@contoso.com'),  
('Janice', 'Galvin', '555.123.4568', 'JGalvin@contoso.com.co'),  
('Zheng', 'Mu', '555.123.4569', 'ZMu@contoso.net');  
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow]  ;  



CREATE USER TestUser WITHOUT LOGIN;  
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[StackOverflow]   TO TestUser;  

EXECUTE AS USER = 'TestUser';  
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StackOverflow]  ;  
REVERT;
```

and you cannot `REVOKE UNMASK` to `sysadmin` and `db_owner`.